# Cancel Task in Place AutoComplete for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Im using Places autocomplete for Android Library below is my code:

```
private void callGoogleAutoComplete(String newText) {
    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setCountry("PK")
            .build();
    Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> results=mGeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(newText,myBounds,typeFilter);

    results.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> task) {
            try {
                String response="";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    results.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
    results.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse autocompletePredictions) {
        }
    });
}
```

Above method is called every time when text change in EditText, I want to cancel pervious call (Task) as on every character task is being generated. But Im unable to cancel Task.

**Note**

I only posted necessary code for Listeners only.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a better way to delay user input. Wait for user finished typing then call your method it helps you. Like this way

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(
new TextWatcher() {
    @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    private Timer timer=new Timer();
    private final long DELAY = 1000; // milliseconds

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO: do what you need here (refresh list)
                    // you will probably need to use runOnUiThread(Runnable action) for some specific actions
                }
            }, 
            DELAY
        );
    }
}
);
```

Comment: PlaceAutoComplete always works as user type. Check search on Play Store